# How to find a method in Eclipse Kepler?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on Eclipse kepler version. The problem I am facing right now is that I need to check if a method is working properly or not but I can't find in which file is it stored. 
Is there any shortcut? 
I tried reading this but even this didn't help. http://rayfd.me/2007/05/20/10-eclipse-navigation-shortcuts-every-java-programmer-should-know/

Comment: If you know the method name(I guess you do), why not simply use the search feature of eclipse and search for it in all the `.java` files of your project?

Comment: Eclipse has a Search menu.

Comment: @DarshanPatel - That's for auto adding/removing the imports. I think you meant `ctrl + o` but even that lists the methods of a file and here the OP doesn't know which file the method is in.

Comment: is there a shortcut for searching inside the Java files? The Ctrl+Shift+r finds the Java files as much as I know. Any such way for methods inside the files?

Comment: @shubhz: click on the Search menu. Search for what you want there. When you have found it (should not take more than 20 seconds), then search for the associated shortcut key.

Answer (score 5):

Just  press and hold ctrl button and place mouse pointer on the method and.. You will see the option open Method Implementation click on it. It will go to that method.

Like this:

[image]

Comment: It's the Command key on OSX, but otherwise yes; exactly right.